# Does Django cache custom tags and filters?

Tags: django, django-templates, python-import

I have a considerable number of custom template tags that perform a variety of functions, including:

- simple string transformation
- display of complex ui elements
- timestamp manipulation and formatting
- handling and display of user avatars
- etc...

**All of these functions reside in a single file**: `app/templatetags/custom_tags.py`.  When I want to use one of these tags in a template, I import all of them using `{% load custom_tags %}`.

**However, only a small subset of the available tags are actually used in any given template.**  In other words, all these functions are being 'loaded' into the template, yet only a few of them are called in a specific web request.

- Is this inefficient, in terms of performance?  Should I be loading code more conservatively -- i.e., splitting up my custom tags into separate files and only loading the subset that I need?
- Or does this not matter, because all tags are loaded in memory -- i.e., subsequent calls to `{% load custom_tags %}` elsewhere in the application won't result in any additional overhead?

I apologize if there are incorrect assumptions or premises in this question.  I'd love to have a better understanding of the implications of importing python code in general, or in a Django environment specifically.

Comment: You should edit your title to something specific like "Does Django cache custom tags and filters?" The current title sounds opinion-based and could be received negatively.

Comment: @approxiblue, many thanks for the suggestion. Part of the problem is definitely that I don't know how to ask the question correctly.

Comment: have you read [this pages](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/dec/04/magic-tags/), maybe it could help you answer your questions !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### For Django <= 1.8:

The `load` tag is defined [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.4/django/template/defaulttags.py#L1117) and actually does the loading [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.4/django/template/defaulttags.py#L1137) and [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.4/django/template/defaulttags.py#L1159). Both places call to `get_library`, defined [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.4/django/template/base.py#L1373). According to the docstrings there, [yes](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.4/django/template/base.py#L1382-L1383), it caches template tag/filter libraries within the same process in the dictionary initalized [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.4/django/template/base.py#L121-L122).

#### For Django 1.9:

The modules for template tags [are now being loaded even earlier](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.9/#template-tag-modules-are-imported-when-templates-are-configured), when the parser is instantiated, and the libraries are being stored directly [on the parser](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9a1/django/template/base.py#L450). Load tags call out to `find_library` [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9a1/django/template/defaulttags.py#L1183) and [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9a1/django/template/defaulttags.py#L1189), which just [gets the already-loaded tag directly from the parser](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9a1/django/template/defaulttags.py#L1132).

#### Aside from the actual loading activity

As @spectras points out below, regardless of the Django version, the tag's loading behavior is, strictly speaking, a side effect, and the tag returns ([<=1.8](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.4/django/template/defaulttags.py#L1164)/[1.9](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9a1/django/template/defaulttags.py#L1191)) a no-op node([<=1.8](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.4/django/template/defaulttags.py#L417-L419)/[1.9](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9a1/django/template/defaulttags.py#L414-L416)), which renders no content--so there's not really a performance consideration as far as that goes.

Comment: You link to lines/files on specific git branches (e.g. stable/1.8.x). The Django devs will commit more to them and your references will become inaccurate. You should link to lines/files on git tags instead.

Comment: You should also add the actual point where `load` tag gets processed after initial parsing: the `LoadNode`, which is just an empty, no-op node.

Comment: @approxiblue Good call. All set there.

Comment: @spectras Added for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed info! Just so I understand -- these concepts are fairly new to me -- when you say 'within the same process' that refers to the web application server?  So the `libraries` dictionary persists between web requests, and therefore there is no performance disadvantage to keeping all custom template tags and filters in the same file as I have been?

Comment: Indeed. What you can concude from all ryanmrubin gathered is the organisation of your custom tags has no influence on your site performance. Each library will be loaded exactly once, either the first time it is used or when you start your server, depending on Django version. If using some multi-process server such as uwsgi, it happens once per process (each process will then serve thousands of requests with no performance penalty).

Comment: @spectras Very helpful and much appreciated.  Learned quite a bit here so thank you all!